# Can't install Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I'm doing the most basic thing possible:

`npm install socket.io`

I get a massive amount of errors, starting from:

```
npm ERR! Error: Socket is not writable
npm ERR!     at Socket._writeOut (net.js:391:11)
npm ERR!     at Socket.write (net.js:377:17)
npm ERR!     at Socket.<anonymous> (util.js:375:21)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
npm ERR!     at Socket._onReadable (net.js:678:14)
npm ERR!     at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/Users/shamoon/local/node/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
```

I have no idea where to begin fixing it

Comment: Which version of node.js are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my `tar` path wasn't correct. All better now =)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to download from [github](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/tarball/master) and `npm install`